# Does a field of transcendence degree n correspond to a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

There's an equivalence of categories between the category of (nonsingular projective) curves over a field $K$ (with dominant morphisms) and finitely generated fields $L/K$ of transcendence degree 1 over $K$.

I assume this fails for higher dimensions, since otherwise I'd expect to know it! Can anyone confirm this, and give me an example/explanation for why it fails?

Comment: The wikipedia article on Birational Geometry is a good quick overview of the story. Two varieties are birationally equivalent if their function-fields are isomorphic. But the varieties need not thereby be isomorphic. This is deep stuff.

Comment: there is a response to the same question here on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100019/function-fields-curves-and-beyond

Comment: Thanks for the answers! So there is an equivalence for higher dimensions, but only up to birational equivalence. That clears things up.

Comment: The big question, I think is to select out of a birational equivalence class a "best" representative. This is more or less the aim of the minimal model program. Already, $\mathbb{P}^2$ and the quadric surface $xy = zw$ are birational but not isomorphic — is it clear that one of these is "better" than the other?